# Why do my VBA custom functions keep triggering too often in Microsoft Excel? Where do I change settings?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have an Excel sheet where I have a lot of cells using a VBA custom function I wrote.  That formula calls a WEBSERVICE to get information over the internet.  I pay for this information and I can see a data charge for each call to the service when looking at an account page in my browser for that service.  This is handy because then I know when the WEBSERVICE calls are executing.   What surprises me, though, is that when I change an unrelated cell in the sheet, there is a delay (for the WEBSERVICE) and I see in my browser that I was just charged for a hit to the service.  I can even type "=1" (which clearly doesn't trigger a function) in a cell off to the right which is not linked to anything and somehow one of the cells elsewhere with my custom function must be executing again (despite not being changed) because it takes 2 seconds to show "1" in the cell and I see the data charge increment in my browser.

What is causing my custom function to execute again?   I thought custom functions  only execute when their cell is changed or when the cells to which they link are changed.  How can I modify the behavior so it works like this?  I don't want these custom functions executing when random unrelated cells are changing.  Where are the settings for this?  Or what VBA lines can I put in my FUNCTION to tell it not to execute except on change of the cell (containing the function) or its subordinate cells (arguments for my function)?

Comment: This is strange behavior, because by default, user-defined functions in Excel are supposed to be non-volatile, which means they will only be recalculated when their input parameters change. Are you sure that none of the input parameters are changing? Do you have `Application.Volatile` in your code anywhere? See here for details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile

Comment: My suggestion is that you make a new worksheet in your file. Put a button on that sheet and put all of the webservice code in that buttons macro and have it cache everything you want on that worksheet. Then anywhere you need to you can reference this sheet. The key being that absolutely no webservice code runs on cell updates at all; it is only ran on button clicked. The truth is that we haven't been given enough information to answer this correctly, which is why this is a comment.

Comment: Upon further testing, I see that even if you use =WEBSERVICE("url")  that it will every time you do "=1" in any random cell in the worksheet.  So the problem is not limited to the use of a custom function.  I wonder if there is some setting anywhere for whether all cells get updated on [the change of another cell].

And, @bdr9, I am not triggering any changes to input parameters nor am I using Application.Volatile.  And, my latest test was with nothing being linked.  Strange.